# Django - How to load paginated Page (next page) into my Template?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-templates, django-views

I have a model named "Person" (List of names).

6 Persons named "Anne". My Pagination is 2 per Page.

When i start a search query on my page for "Anne". I get the Response of **"6 Results"**, it shows me the first two Results and it displays **"Page 1 of 3. Next**. So far everything fine. but when i press **"next"** the Browser only updates to 
**..../post_searchtwo/?page=2** but the next two Results will not show up.

(Using Django version 2.2.2 with PostgreSQL 11)

thanks in advance.

**views.py**

```
def post_searchtwo(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Person.objects.annotate(
                search=SearchVector('city', 'last_name', 'first_name')
            ).filter(search=query)


    paginator = Paginator(results, 2) # --- Show 2 items per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        post_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        post_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        post_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        'form': form,
        'query': query,
        'page': page,
        'post_list': post_list,
        'results':  results
        }
    return  render(request,'search/post_searchtwo.html', context)
```

**my template / post_searchtwo.htnl**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block custom_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/home_styles.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="." method="get">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

    {%  if  query   %}

    <h3>Posts   containing  "{{ query   }}"</h3>
    <h3>
        {%  with results.count  as  total_results   %}
        Found   {{  total_results   }}  result{{    total_results|pluralize }}
        {%  endwith %}
    </h3>

            {%  for post in post_list   %}

            <h4>
                <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url   }}">{{  post.first_name }} {{   post.last_name  }}</a>
            </h4>

            {%  empty   %}

            <p>Theren are no results for your query.</p>

            {%  endfor  %}


    <div class="col-6 offset-md-3">
        {%  include "pagination.html"   with    page=post_list  %}
    </div>

    {% endif %}


{%  endblock    %}
```

**.../pagination.htnl**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {%  if  page.has_previous   %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {%  endif   %}
        <span class="current">
            Page    {{  page.number }}  of  {{  page.paginator.num_pages    }}.
        </span>
        {%  if  page.has_next   %}
        <a href="?page={{   page.next_page_number   }}">Next</a>
        {%  endif   %}
    </span>
</div>
```

> Update: Thanks to @Daniel Roseman

as Daniel pointed out (down below) here the changes.

**.../pagination.htnl**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {%  if  page.has_previous   %}
        <a href="?query={{ query }}&page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {%  endif   %}
        <span class="current">
            Page    {{  page.number }}  of  {{  page.paginator.num_pages    }}.
        </span>
        {%  if  page.has_next   %}
        <a href="?query={{ query }}&page={{ page.next_page_number   }}">Next</a>
        {%  endif   %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to include the query in the next and previous links.

Comment: i putted **{{ request.get_full_path }}** before **?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}**. You mean that? now i get ...**/post_searchtwo/?query=anne?page=2**  response in my Browser adress. But also the whole query gets updated and shows "Posts containing "anne?page=2"".

Comment: No not the full path, just the query. And you need & as the separator.

Comment: So now it is like this **<a href="{{ query }}?page={{ page.next_page_number }}"** wich leads to  this **..../post_searchtwo/anne?page=2**. But what is a seperator?

Comment: No. `<a href="?query={{ query }}&page={{ page.next_page_number }}"`.